# Let F denote $M(R)$, the set of all mappings $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, made into a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let F denote $M(\mathbb{R})$, the set of all mappings $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, made into a group

Let

$$H= \{ f \in F : f(x) \in  \mathbb Z   \mbox{ for each } x
 \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $F$. State clearly the properties of $\mathbb Z$ that you use.

to prove that we need to check that:

- H is not empty
- if $a,b \in z $ then $a*b \in H$
- if $a \in H$ then $a^{-1} \in H$ 
  I confused how to prove that H is not empty.

Comment: If you have a subset of a group and you need to prove that it is a subgroup, you don't have to check associativity. Actually you need to prove that $0 \in H$, and it is closed under sums and inverses.

Comment: @Crostul if you're proving that it's a subgroup, then proving $0 \in H$ is redundant if you're going on to prove that $H$ is closed under sums and inverses (and in particular, sums of inverses)

Comment: thanks, i just edited the question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not quite because then  the empty set could fit in that...One *must somehow* show the set is not empty *first*, and then that it is closed and etc.

Comment: @sh.alzoubi $\;F\;$ is a group... **under what operation** ?